# what is apply method in Scala, especially used in type definition

Tags: scala, generics, apply

I know that `apply` method is syntactic sugar when used in companion object. 
However, what is `apply` method for when it is used in type definition just like below?

```
type Applyn = {
    def apply[A](f: A=>A, n: Int, x: A): A
}
```

Is there a deference between this sentence?
As I guess, this sentence is used for assigning generic function value to Applyn.

For example, by using above sentence, we can make

```
(Int=>Int, Int, Int)=>Int
```

```
(String=>String, Int, String)=>String
```

etc., into only a single type `Applyn`.

Is this correct?

Comment: It was called `structural type`, `Applyn` just refers to any type which have a method `def apply[A](f: A=>A, n: Int, x: A): A`

Comment: Then, it does not refer to a function itself, but refers to any type with `def apply[A](f: A=>A, n: Int, x: A): A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is a structural type.  It doesn't refer to any specific type but any type that has a method `apply[A](f: A=>A, n: Int, x: A): A`.  Functions have an apply method, so a function with the correct signature applies, but it's also possible to create types that have that apply method that are not functions. Imagine the following.

```
object NotAFunction {
  def apply[A](f: A=>A, n: Int, x: A): A = {...}
}
```

This object doesn't extend Function, so it is not a function but it still satisfies the structural type requirement.

Structural types provide a nice syntax but they are very slow, so they should be avoided where possible, especially in performance critical code.